# Codeigniter cookies encryptiion

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, encryption

why does my cookies are not encrypted? i see them as plain text and i can edit them easly, cause it's plain text :O

i'm using:

```
    $config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'sess_id';
    $config['sess_expiration']      = 0; //24hours -> 8640
    $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
    $config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
    $config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
    $config['sess_table_name']      = 'session';
    $config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
    $config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
    $config['sess_time_to_update']  = 3000000000;
$config['encryption_key'] = 'dfs78fh834fh83h4fhhsdifsihdfh99inf83kjwnefkjwenfknwkejnfowejnf82';
```

and to set cookie i use an hooks that looks like this:

```
function setUserCountry($country){

    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->input->set_cookie(
      array(
        'name'=>'user_country',
        'value'=>str_replace(array('"',"'",">","<"),"",$country),
        'expire'=>'8650000000',
        'secure'=>TRUE
        ));
    }
```

the hook is called pre_controller:

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = //run my cookie hook setUserCountry() method
```

and this is how the cookie looks once is created:

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to encrypt a cookie value? If it's sensitive info, it belongs in the session.

Comment: cause sessions expires on browser close and cookies not :P !? @Pekka웃

Comment: you can make a session cookie not expire when the browser closes, although that can be an issue security-wise. But if you need to store data beyond the current session, why not store it in the user record?

Comment: Cookies are treated as such (plain text saving), while sessions - although being cookies themselves - are instead enctypted. If you want encrypted cookies, you need to do that manually (via the encryption library). Your complain is like "My admin pages are protectd, why my regular pages aren't  instead?". Different purposes, different treatment

Comment: @DamienPirsy if CI has no automatic option please feel free to answer the question and i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are feeding an array to the set_cookie() $name parameter, with secure = true.

```
if ($secure == FALSE AND config_item('cookie_secure') != FALSE)
        {
            $secure = config_item('cookie_secure');
        }
```

This code inside system/core/Input.php will cause problems. So unless you either turn off global cookie encryption or leave out $secure in your array, it should work.

**EDIT**
[Cookies not beeing set, codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253195/cookies-not-beeing-set-codeigniter)
correctly points out the problem

You need to load the cookie helper though. Also, use the post_controller_constructor hook instead.
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html

Also, isn't it better to just use this way? http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY
and add your cookies to the extended core controller.

Comment: hi i tryed but the problem persists, unbelievable :O i have really no idea on why it happens, may be cause i not use cookie helper and i use input class for setting cookies? :O

Comment: i all tryed these and some of these solutions already are on my app, problem persist, since cookies are created but not encrypted :/

Answer (score 4):

For encrypt the cookie in codeigniter make changes in the config.php file at

```
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
```

change this line to

```
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
```

Also set the encryption key at

```
$config['encryption_key'] = "";
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you shouldn't rely on storing sensitive data with the client, even encrypted. You're more secure to just store the session id (or for longer life, a user id and checksum) in the cookie and keep the sensitive information under your own control in a database (again, encrypted). Using SSL mitigates this issue but it's still not an ideal solution. Also, Cookies can be cleared which may pose problems

Comment: @user2326544 hey wtf you're right, but i already use it $config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE; so the problem now is understanding why it doesn't encrypts them :O , i edit my answer thanks